# what width to set an UITableViewCell in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

What width should I set a UITableViewCell in Interface Builder?

Background - So I'm creating a custom view (i.e. not subclassing) that I will use.

Some questions around the question:

- should it be a fixed width? but then what it the strategy for how it handles being put into EDIT mode then - does this require another "stretch" type setting in IB to compliment the fixed width?
- what about what happens when the iPhone is put into landscape mode then
- even without landscape mode or useage of any of the other cell views (e.g. for image etc), does the width of my custom view have to equal the width of the iPhone screen for optimal resolution - or in other words could I just create a much bigger view in Interface Builder (easy to work with / read) and then IOS would auto-scale the width accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up the `autoresizingMask`s appropriately to solve the edit mode and landscape issues, it doesn't really matter what size the cell is in Interface Builder as it will automatically adjust correctly for whatever size it winds up at in the actual table.

Comment: oh - to understand than - would it be OK to draw it much larger in Interface Builder than, so it makes it easily to lay things out - and then it would autosize down... ie if one did this it wouldn't cause and performance or scaling issues?

Comment: I like to try to keep it about the normal size (e.g. around 320 px wide), as that way I won't accidentally try to cram in more than will really fit.